# Using R to split text into a labeled table

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I have a dataset formatted like

```
"Name:\t\t Foo Bar \t Account Name: \t\t USERIDXXX \t"
```

as a column in a data.table. I would like to transform it into something like

```
Name:      Account Name: 
Foo Bar    USERIDXXX
```

I tried a few data.table functions, but have not been successful.

```
library(data.table)
x <- as.data.table("Name:\t\t Foo Bar \t Account Name: \t\t USERIDXXX \t")

x[, variables := tstrsplit(V1, "\t")]
```

Expected a table of the exported values. I got a warning and the following output:

> In [.data.table(x, , :=(variables, tstrsplit(V1, "\t"))) :
>     Supplied 6 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'variables' (5 unused)

```
                                          V1 variables
1: Name:\t\t Foo Bar \t Account Name: \t\t USERIDXXX \t     Name:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the input is as shown in the Note at the end.  Replace space, tab, space with newline and add a newline at the end of each line.  Then it is in dcf format and can be read in using `read.dcf`

```
s2 <- gsub("( \t )|$", "\n", s)
read.dcf(textConnection(s2))
```

giving this character matrix:

```
     Name      Account Name
[1,] "Foo Bar" "USERIDXXX" 
[2,] "Foo Bar" "USERIDXXX"
```

No packages are used.

### Note

```
s <- "Name:\t\t Foo Bar \t Account Name: \t\t USERIDXXX \t"
s <- c(s, s)
```

This gives the following input:

```
s
## [1] "Name:\t\t Foo Bar \t Account Name: \t\t USERIDXXX \t"
## [2] "Name:\t\t Foo Bar \t Account Name: \t\t USERIDXXX \t"
```